# Is it possible to change the .exe file during its excecution?

Tags: c, file, exe

For example: I make a game and at the end of the game i have a score. I could save the score by means of a new file. But would it be possible to allocate some space within the .exe file which is my game, so that I dont have any extra file?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but please don't do this. Executable files are not for storing information that is otherwise unrelated to the application.

Comment: It is possible, viruses do that all the time. Of course, user access control will prevent this on windows systems >= vista if the file is installed normally. And you'll probably get lots of support calls from customers whose virus scanner complains about modified exe files and thus are afraid your exe is a virus.

Comment: I simpliest create a file. Also, probably you could have a unique file with all the puntuations.

Comment: If your goal is to not have a visible file, then you should use the application settings path of Windows, where you are supposed to store files like this, without those files showing up in the user's file manager. Or, you can store the scored in the registry. Take your pick. Storing them inside the exe, is the worst pick :-P (Unless you're doing it for general hacking around and learning purposes, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can, but not as much as you used to be able to, and you shouldn't.

It's bad because:

1. AV software will spot the change and flag it as a possible virus infection
2. You will incorrectly invalidate windows pre-fetching (potentially slowing app loading).
3. You will need to run the app with admin permission (a bad idea) to gain write access to the exe.
4. It breaks the expected layout and distribution of things. Windows has expected places to put this sort of thing, use it.

Comment: That's not an answer to a perfectly valid question :-/

Comment: @Nikos I think 'no you shouldn't' is an answer because he substantiates it with arguments.

Comment: @remyabel Yeah, but an answer is still missing. Learning how to modify an exe file is actually a recommended learning activity. You learn lots of stuff about the OS.

Comment: @Nikos It would be easier to disassemble the exe and change the score than it would be to modify the exe while running, IMO, largely defeating OP's effort. Maybe he could have a "game file", which encrypts the data somehow which is decrypted when read via the exe. That would make it less trivial to cheat and change the score.

Comment: @remyabel No matter how you store the score, you can just use Cheat Engine (www.cheatengine.org) and modify the score in-memory. Storage doesn't matter.

Comment: @Nikos Or inject a DLL. But I think we're getting off topic here.